# Socket gets disconnected while user selects image in browser on iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, node.js, iphone, sockets, ipad

We have created a node js web application, there is a functionality, user clicks on upload button and selects images or clicks picture with camera. But when user tries to upload the image captured through iphone/ipad camera. I used chrome browser for iOS.

This is just a client crash (not the server crash. confirmed this with opening two different sessions on two different devices. When client of one device crashes, other works fine and no crash logs printed in server).

I have done some experiments with two Iphones.... iPhoneA with ios version 11.2.5 and iPhoneB with 11.4.1.

It was working fine with iPhoneA  and did not observe any crash for the same.

For iPhoneB I observed

1. When captured image through camera and waited for 5 seconds and then selected the 'Use Photo' option, crash was observed.
2. When captured image through camera and waited for 5 seconds and then selected the 'Cancel' option, crash was observed.
3. When went to browse image and waited for 5 seconds and then selected the image or selected the cancel option, crash was observed.
4. When I do all the above processes with great speed with less than 3 seconds , there was No Crash observed.

I see this occurs when we switch through the application (from browser to other app to select image) browser app goes to sleep and socket disconnects ,crash happens (may be introduced in 11.4.1 latest version). To confirm this I have tried two more scenarios.

1. Opened application in browser , minimized it for 5 seconds , opened other apps then reopened browser , it was crashed.
2. Opened settings/restore feature, selected From File option and opened browse option waited for 5 seconds , came back to browser, it was crashed.
   Socket is getting disconnected when browser application goes to sleep.

Can you help me to stop this crashing or anything to restrict socket getting disconnected?

EDIT: [Video link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ix-dEob5LYQD-mvBfxkqHvr_jC9po_vt) added.

Comment: what is your customer app?
Is it iOS app?

Comment: What do you mean by "I used chrome browser for iOS." Is the app that crashes not iOS app

Comment: @iOS_Developer, no its a website, I run it on chrome browser... theres option to upload images, when I go back to site after selecting the image, page gets refreshed

Comment: Please check error video link added in question.

Comment: so you just need to track reloading issue.

Comment: yes, can you help in some direction I can move further?

Comment: I work on mobile technologies only, i have shared this question with a friend who works with web sockets he will help soon

Comment: @iOS_Developer, thank you very much